# Shell append string after last match

Tags: bash, text-processing, scripting

I would like to insert a string after the last match, example:

String to insert after last instance of banana: Orange

**Input**

```
Apple
Banana
Apple
Banana
```

**Output**

```
Apple
Banana
Apple
Banana
Orange
```

I am trying to do this with XML tags. I have already worked out how to add the start tag.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18291341/sed-only-the-last-match-pattern     - this would help

Comment: If you want to do this with XML tags, parse the XML and search for the tag. There is no guarantee that the element with that tag doesn't span multiple lines. Inserting on a line by line basis is in general not possible for XML. Your example doesn't show that if there were a word `Pear` on a line after the second `Banana` you would get `OrangePear` on one line, because your insertion doesn't contain a newline.

Answer (score 2):

Short and simple, to do *exactly* what was asked:

```
printf '%s\n' '0?Banana?a' Orange . x | ex file.txt
```

If you would rather see what is going to be saved to the file (rather than immediately saving the modifications), use:

```
printf '%s\n' '0?Banana?a' Orange . %p | ex file.txt
```

---

What this does:

From the very start of the file (`0`) search *backwards* (`?regex?`) for the next instance (wrapping around) of "Banana", then append (`a`) the line "Orange".  The period ends the appending, and the `x` saves and exits.

Comment: Equivalent on FreeBSD: `printf '%s\n' '?Banana?a' Orange . x | ex -c 1 file.txt` where `-c 1` is the way to get to first line of the file.

Comment: @zezollo does that work if "Banana" appears on the first line of the file (as well as elsewhere)?

Comment: I've tested on several cases (with several "Banana"s, one being at the first line, also with a single "Banana" line (at start of the file) or with a file containing exclusively "Banana" lines), and couldn't find a case that does not work. If there's no "Banana" at all, then one gets an error ("Impossible to find pattern").

Answer (score 1):

```
tac a | sed '0,/Banana/{s/Banana/Orange\nBanana/}' | tac
```

Will do it !

EDIT : Modified from the answer to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18291341/sed-only-the-last-match-pattern

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e:n -e'/\n.*Banana/!{$!{N' \
         -e'/Banana/bn' -eb -e\}\
         -e's/\n/&Orange&/;t'   \
         -e'/Banana/a\' -eOrange\
    -e\} -e'P;D' <<\IN
Apple
Banana
Apple
Banana
IN
```

---

```
Apple
Banana
Apple
Banana
Orange
```

That should work pretty reliably. It will buffer in pattern space *between* occurrences of *`Banana`* in input - printing to stdout all of the last buffer group when a new one is matched. And the last occurrence of *`Banana`* should be handled correctly regardless of *where* it occurs in input. And it doesn't need to read its whole input file before writing any output, either.